# Rails - Why is " source 'https://rubygems.org' " giving -bash No such file or directory"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, gemfile

I am trying to install `bootstrap-sass` gem in mac terminal:

```
$ source 'https://rubygems.org' -bash: https://rubygems.org/
No such file or directory
```

I have searched everywhere and all the sites are pointing me to fix the SSL but my SSL is all updated and the certificates too. I can't seem to find any reason on why is this happening. 
If someone could please help me with this issue.

Regards

Comment: what does `gem install bootstrap-sass` return?

Comment: Why sourcing rubygems.org? That's non-sense to me...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are typing this into a bash prompt, however

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
```

Is a directive that goes into your Gemfile (which is a file that specifies the set of gems that a project uses).

To install a gem, the bash command is

```
gem install bootstrap-sass
```